# How to send an email with mail gem in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mail-gem

I am trying to send an email using [mail gem](https://github.com/mikel/mail). But Unfortunately it is not working.
This is my controller.

```
    def create
      fn = params["firstname"]
      ln = params["lastname"]
      email = params["email"]
      file = params["file"]
      summery = params["summery"]
      email_body = "Hello\n This is Your favorite website.\nA I want to personaly say hi."
      mail = Mail.new do
        from 'someone@gmail.com'
        to email
        subject "Saying Hi"
        body email_body
      end
      mail.add_file(filename: file.original_filename, content: File.read(file.tempfile.path)) unless file.nil?
      mail.deliver!
      render json: {message: "A bug has been created", success: true}, status: 201
    end
```

This code is producing this error

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25:

However when I am installing the [mailcatcher](https://github.com/sj26/mailcatcher) and configure my controller to send the mail to mailcatcher, I can see the email in my mailcatcher UI.

```
Mail.defaults do
 delivery_method :smtp, address: "localhost", port: 1025
end
```

Also I have add this two lines to my config/environment/development.rb

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true 
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
```

From my searches I saw that some people are mentioning that dont send email on development mode, however on this case I really want to test the full capability.

**Update**

As @Uzbekjon and  @SimoneCarletti suggested I change my code to use the ActionMailer. I created the a file in app/mailer/ and I am calling that from my controller.

```
  def create
    fn = params["firstname"]
    ln = params["lastname"]
    email = params["email"]
    file = params["file"]
    summery = params["summery"]
     email_body = "Hello\n This is Your favorite website.\nA I want to personaly say hi."
    WelcomeMailer.welcome(fn, ln, email, file, email_body).deliver_now
    render json: {message: "An Email has been send", success: true}, status: 201
  end
```

and This is my mailer

```
class WelcomeMailer < ActionMailer::Base
  default from: "someone@yahoo.com"

  def welcome(first_name, last_name, email, file, email_body)
    attachments["#{file.original_filename}"] = File.read("#{file.tempfile.path}")
 mail(
   to: email, 
   subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site', 
   body: email_body
 )
  end
end
```

However I am still getting the same error.

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25:

**Answer**

So I found the solution. Yes you need to use the ActionMailer. After that you need to go to the *config/environments/development.rb* , and modify and add these lines:

```
  config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
  config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
  # SMTP settings for gmail
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
    :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
    :port                 => 587,
    :user_name            => "YOUR EMAIL",
    :password             => "YOUR Password",
    :authentication       => "plain",
    :enable_starttls_auto => true
  }
```

Also If Gmail complained about this:

> Net::SMTPAuthenticationError - 534-5.7.9 Application-specific password required

Go to this [link](https://www.google.com/settings/security/lesssecureapps) and let less secure application access Gmail.

Other configurations are available for other services like Yahoo. Just Google it.

Comment: Why are you using the Mail gem directly, instead of the ActiveRecord mailer library that is part of Rails?

Comment: @SimoneCarletti that is my next step if no one could figure this one out, do you suggest the Active Record Mailer over the gem?

Comment: Yes, you should definitely use `ActionMailer` (and not `ActiveRecord` which is the ORM). FYI `ActionMailer` wraps the `mail` gem.

Comment: @SimoneCarletti I have added the code with the ActionMailer, however I am getting a same error.

Comment: Do I need to run a SMTP server or something. Sorry I am not really familiar with the process.

Answer (score 1):

> Errno::ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused - connect(2) for "localhost" port 25:

Looks like `mail` gem is trying to connect to your local smtp server on port 25. Most probably you don't have the service running and receiving connections on port 25.

To solve, install and run `sendmail` or `postfix` on your machine.

PS. Use [`ActionMailer`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html).

Comment: I have updated the code with the ActionMailer but I am getting a same error.

Comment: As I wrote in my answer, the problem is that you don't have "mail server" running on your local machine. To solve it, you need to install one. For example `sendmail` or `postfix`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a mail server running on port 25. You can install [postfix](http://www.postfix.org/) and start the server using

```
sudo postfix start
```

And then modify the settings in `config/environments/development.rb`

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :sendmail
```

Hope this helps.